# How to split excluding a specific string in markdown text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making an app that splits the markdown content like the one below into a string of '---' and displays it as a slide. However, there is an error of splitting equally even if there is --- in the code block as shown below.

How can I split only '---' as a string, excluding code block?

````
#Title

---

```js

Please implement the method to display the console result below.

const app = () => { ... }

// output

-
---  // this is problem
--
...
````

Answer (score 0):

Use look-behind and look-ahead, look-behind only works in Chrome.

````
let input = '```---```---abc'
input.split(/(?!<`)---(?!`)/) // ["```---```", "abc"]
````